# Control column width with multicol and minipage

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage, multicol

Here is my code:

```
%

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{float} %figure inside minipage
\pagestyle{empty}



%\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[landscape,left=0.6in,right=0.8in,top=0.2in,bottom=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstset{frame=tb,
 backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour}, 
  language=Python,
  aboveskip=2.5mm,
  belowskip=0mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3
}
%\usepackage{colortbl}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}



%\advance\topmargin-.9in
%\advance\textheight1in
\advance\textwidth 1in
\advance\oddsidemargin-0.6in %plus proche de 0 on d&cale tout vers la droite
%\advance\evensidemargin-0.6in
%\parindent2pt
\parskip2pt %Espacement entre les block (minipage)
%\newcommand{\hr}{\centerline{\rule{3.5in}{1pt}}}
%\colorbox[HTML]{e4e4e4}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{texto}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{titlesec}
% \titleformat{<command>}[<shape>]{<format>}{<label>}{<sep>}{<before-code>}[<after-code>]
\titleformat{\section}%command
{\bf \normalsize  }% format applied to label+text   \color{blue}
{{\thesection } - }% label {{\thesection } - }
{0pt}%sep
{\underline}

\titlespacing{\section}%command
{20pt}%left
{5pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}%beforesep
{2pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}%aftersep

\begin{document}

\begin{center}{\huge{\textbf{Cassandra Cheat Sheet  \\ }}}
 \end{center}



\begin{multicols*}{3}

\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=black, fill=white, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=10pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=black,   text=white, font=\bfseries]

%------------ Cell ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
\end{lstlisting}

\end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Keyspaces};
\end{tikzpicture}
%------------ End ---------------


\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
#List of databases:
DESCRIBE keyspaces; 

#Detailed list of databases
SELECT * FROM system_schema.keyspaces;

#Create database rebar suitable for development:
CREATE KEYSPACE killrvideo
WITH replication = {
  'class':'SimpleStrategy',
  'replication_factor' : 1
};

#Switch to database rebar:
USE killrvideo;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Keyspaces};
\end{tikzpicture}
%------------ End ---------------

%------------ Cell ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
#List of tables:
DESCRIBE tables;

#Describe table
DESCRIBE table videos;

#Create a table:
CREATE TABLE videos ( 
  video_id TIMEUUID, 
  added_date TIMESTAMP, 
  description TEXT, 
  title TEXT, 
  user_id UUID, 
  PRIMARY KEY (video_id) 
);


\end{lstlisting}

\end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Tables};
\end{tikzpicture}
%------------ End ---------------

%------------ Cell ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
#External file of cqlsh commands
cqlsh:killrvideo> source '/home/CassandraProgs/inputfile.txt';

#
\end{lstlisting}

\end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {External files};
\end{tikzpicture}
%------------ End ---------------

%------------ Cell ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
#List all types
cqlsh:tutorialspoint> DESCRIBE TYPES;

#Create type
CREATE TYPE tutorialspoint.card_details(   
        num int,
        name text,
        phone set<int>,
        mail text);

#Describe
cqlsh:tutorialspoint> DESCRIBE TYPES;

\end{lstlisting}

\end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Type};
\end{tikzpicture}
%------------ End ---------------

%------------ Cell ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
\begin{minipage}{0.43\textwidth}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Data Type  & Constants         & Description                               \\
Bytes      &                   &                                           \\
blob       & blobs             & Represents arbitrary bytes                \\
String     &                   &                                           \\
ascii      & strings           & Represents ASCII character string         \\
text       & strings           & Represents UTF8 encoded string            \\
varchar    & strings           & Represents uTF8 encoded string            \\
inet       & strings           & Represents an IP address, IPv4 or IPv6    \\
Boolean    &                   &                                           \\
Boolean    & booleans          & Represents true or false                  \\
Numeric    &                   &                                           \\
int        & integers          & Represents 32-bit signed int              \\
varint     & integers          & Represents arbitrary-precision integer    \\
bigint     & bigint            & Represents 64-bit signed long             \\
double     & integers          & Represents 64-bit IEEE-754 floating point \\
counter    & integers          & Represents counter column                 \\
decimal    & integers, floats  & Represents variable-precision decimal     \\
float      & integers, floats  & Represents 32-bit IEEE-754 floating point \\
Identifier &                   &                                           \\
timestamp  & integers, strings & Represents a timestamp                    \\
timeuuid   & uuids             & Represents type 1 UUID                    \\
uuid       & uuids             & Represents type 1 or type 4              
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Data type};
\end{tikzpicture}
%------------ End ---------------








\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

and here is my rendering:
https://snag.gy/oL8hyF.jpg

As you can see i didn't manage to reduce the horizontal spacing between the block between the box tikzpicture.
Is it possible ? If yes how ?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... If possible, please post the image into your question itself, as some of the browser didn't allow the image what you mentioned...

Comment: First, lose the table [H].  It still thinks it is a float and you can't use floats inside other boxes.  If you want a caption, use \captionof{table}{...} from the caption or capt-of packages.

Comment: A \noindent, or restoring the \parindent2pt would help.  Instead of multicols, you could group them into three varwidth environments (varwidth package) side-by-sice.  Of course you would have to decide which tikzpictures go into which columns ahead of time.  There is also paracol and flowfram, but you would have to set the widths ahead of time.